# How to re-size Paradox tables after records have been deleted?

Tags: paradox

I am using the Paradox 9 app as bundled with WordPerfect 2000. After deleting thousands of records from the table, the filesize remains at 500 kB even though there are now only 12 records. Is there a way to decrease the filesize to what it would be as if I had re-created the table and entered the 12 records from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the table in Paradox 9. Go to Format --> Restructure Table. Check the "Pack Table" checkbox, then click Save.